# Eclipse, Tomcat and MacOS X: user.dir is not correct

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I installed tomcat and I am using it with Eclipse Luna Java EE. The problem is that one of my classes reads a text file. When I execute it as a java application, it reads the file correctly. When I execute it on the server ("Run on the server"), it then crashes with a nullpointexception.

I checked the path where it is reading the file. When it executes on the server, it tries to read the file from "Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/". Just for the sake of it, I tried to put the text file right there, and it does not say it didn't find it anymore, but whenever I try to use Scanner to read it, it produces this:

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=.][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

and never goes beyond a single line (hasNext is always false).

So, my questions are:

1 - How can I get it to look for the .txt file elsewhere (on the root of the project, for example)?

2 - Why scanner only finds content on the file when running the class as a java application, not on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who had the same problem:

I was printing the Scanner object, that's why I was getting that text. 
That understood, Scanner still wasn't reading through the file, and I read elsewhere that this tends to be an encoding issue.

Somehow, Scanner worked properly only when I informed the encoding of the file I was reading. So

```
Scanner f=new Scanner (fileobject, "UTF-8");
```

worked for me.

As of the user.dir, I changed the attribute of Apache tomcat on Eclipse, by choosing "Run configurations", selecting Apache, and in Attributes, I selected my current workplace.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the app as a *web* app then you should be looking for either:

- an absolute path
- a resource (e.g., on the classpath)
- a context-relative path

Absolute paths are easy and can be defined using init parameters, system properties, config files, etc.

Classpath resources must live on the app's classpath.

Relative resources are off the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)).

The functionality that *uses* the file should be usable regardless of where the file comes from, e.g., it should take a stream or something. That way the functionality can be used from both your web app, standalone classes like a `static main` thing, or a unit test.

Comment: How to I check the app's classpath and how do I get it when creating the File object?

Comment: You don't need to do anything like that, use getResourceAsStream.

Comment: But can I use Scanner to parse the info I want if I use getResourceAsStream?

Comment: @francisaugusto http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Got it. I managed to get the file correctly (using file and getting the attributes fixed on tomcat's configuration at Eclipse). So now it does find the file. But it seems that Scanner does not parse it, and always give me the output above, and does not read a single line of the file. Interestingly enough, if I run it as a java application, it reads fine.

Comment: This is embarassing, and I apologize: the stuff I posted above was because I was printing an Scanner object. Now I just need to find out why the scanner is not reading the text. Probably an encoding issue.

Comment: @francisaugusto Something the default `toString()` can cause some confusion. I18N *always* causes confusion.